# Angular no crea el archivo app.module.ts.¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: angular, routing

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image]
no se que esta mal, no me pregunta sobre el routing pero si sobre SSR. El problema es que no me crea la carpeta app module ts.
adjuntos las versiones instaladas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por defecto Angular 17 crea un proyecto que usa la nueva API [standalone](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components).

Puedes cambiar eso poniendo en `false` la opción al momento de crear el proyecto:

```
ng new hierbaMala --standalone=false
```

Comment: Solo aclarar que no es necesario hacerlo por consola la creación de módulos, se pueden crear manualmente.

Comment: si, pero la configuracion en angular.json, espera compilar standalone. tambien hay que editar eso, y otras cosas.