# No se genera los archivos "app-routing.module.ts" y "app.module.ts"

Tags: angular, routing

Cuando creo un proyecto Angular con `ng new nombre_proyecto` no se genera la estructura de `routing` tradicional, es decir, que no aparecen los archivos *app-routing.module.ts* y *app.module.ts*, sino que aparecen los archivos *app.config.ts* y *app.routes.ts*.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Angular no crea el archivo app.module.ts.¿Que estoy haciendo mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/607731/angular-no-crea-el-archivo-app-module-ts-que-estoy-haciendo-mal)

Answer (score 2):

Lo más probable es que estés trabajando con la nueva versión de Angular, que ya viene por defecto el modo standalone. para crearlo con módulos agrega la opción
**"--standalone false"**, por ejemplo.

```
    ng new app-with-modules --routing --standalone false
```